# .htaccess not working with GoDaddy

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**This is my `.htaccess` rewrite:**

```
Options +Indexes
ErrorDocument 400 /notfound.php
ErrorDocument 401 /notfound.php
ErrorDocument 403 /notfound.php
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
ErrorDocument 500 /notfound.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.xml(.*) $1.php$2 [nocase]
```

I haven't had trouble using this on any server other than GoDaddy. The sites use a custom CMS with a file called "pages" (not "pages.php") that links to the page alias (e.g. http://www.domain.com/pages/page-alias) and that works everywhere.

The home page is fine. But when going to the page alias, the pages file doesn't work.

I need to use a "pages.php" file to make it work (linking to http://www.domain.com/pages.php/page-alias).

Is this an issue with the `.htaccess` file on the GoDaddy server?

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Not sure of this will help, but some servers require you to set `RewriteBase /`. I've only read this in certain packaged `.htaccess` files, but have never experienced it. Might be worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

With GoDaddy, you need to turn off Multiviews:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

<sub>[[source](http://davidwalsh.name/mod_rewrite-htaccess-godaddy)]</sub>